# Cannot return value to PostExecute in Asyntask android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I got an `AsyncTask` for image recognition, after the `doInBackground()` finish and value return to `onPostExecute()`, I would like to use an interface to get the value back to `MainActivity`, I am not sure why the return tmp is skipped when I run the debugger, any ideas?

```
private class ProcessImageLocally extends AsyncTask<ImageItem, Void, ImageItem>{ //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    public AsyncReponseForImageItem response = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        localProcessBegin();            //Process data locally
    }

    @Override
    protected ImageItem doInBackground(ImageItem... params) {
        //**************processing locally*****************
        try {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0].getBitmapPath());

            Bitmap croppedBitmap = getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), INPUT_SIZE, bm);
            final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = classifier.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);

            String resultStr = results.toString();
            String trimResult = resultStr.substring(resultStr.indexOf("[")+1,resultStr.indexOf("]")).trim();

            String localId = params[0].getId();
            trimResult = trimResult.substring(0,trimResult.indexOf(")")) + " likely)";

            Bitmap thumbnail = getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), 50, bm);
            ImageItem tmp = new ImageItem(localId, imgToString(thumbnail), trimResult);
            return tmp;     //Skip to the outside return
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ImageItem imageItem) {
        response.asyncFinish(imageItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked in debugging mode if IOException is thrown in catch? Maybe it goes something wrong in try block.

Comment: Can you provide a logcat?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure why the return tmp is skipped when I run the debugger

Your code is inside a `try catch`, which means, if any `exception` appears before `return tmp;`, all code after the line with the error does not execute anymore. That being said, there is something going wrong above `return tmp`.

When an `exception` happens, your app jumps in the `catch` block, where you write `e.printStacktrace`. This will write the error in your logcat.

After that it will `return null;`, since there was no more work to do in the `catch` block.

Please check what happens inside the `try` block, and fix it's errors.